# Cannot load NICFI data using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, planet

I want to use the images provided by Planet & NICFI (https://www.planet.com/nicfi/#sign-up). This images are now available on GEE as shown in the dataset catalog in Google Earth engine: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/tags/nicfi.

when I run the [test scrip](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples:Datasets/projects_planet-nicfi_assets_basemaps_asia) in my JS code editor:

```js
var nicfi = ee.ImageCollection('projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/asia');

// Filter basemaps by date and get the first image from filtered results
var basemap= nicfi.filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-03-01','2021-07-01')).first();

Map.setCenter(107, 10, 4);

var vis = {"bands":["R","G","B"],"min":64,"max":5454,"gamma":1.8};

Map.addLayer(basemap, vis, '2021-03 mosaic');
Map.addLayer(
    basemap.normalizedDifference(['N','R']).rename('NDVI'),
    {min:-0.55,max:0.8,palette: [
        '8bc4f9', 'c9995c', 'c7d270','8add60','097210'
    ]}, 'NDVI', false);
```

It works as expected.

when I translate this code in Python and try to display it using `geemap`:

```py
from geemap import Map 
import ee 

ee.Initialize()

Map = Map()

nicfi = ee.ImageCollection('projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/asia')

# Filter basemaps by date and get the first image from filtered results
basemap = nicfi.filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-03-01','2021-07-01')).first()

Map.setCenter(107, 10, 4)

vis = {"bands":["R","G","B"],"min":64,"max":5454,"gamma":1.8}

Map.addLayer(basemap, vis, '2021-03 mosaic')

Map
```

I get the following error:

> EEException: ImageCollection.load: ImageCollection asset 'projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/asia' not found.

How can a collection be available in the JS code editor but not in the Python API ?

I'm using the same account to authenticate in both services (Python API and JS code editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had updated my NICFI data access. If anyone face this issue, you should reset your GEE authentification in your Python environment and start again:

```
earthengine authenticate
```

Now the code run on both platform

Answer (score 0):

You should register at Planet.com and go to settings and enable access of planet data to GEE by specifying the Gmail ID used for GEE. It will then allow access.